# Как присвоить значение в MutableStateFlow из сети?

Tags: android

Как присвоить значение value в MutableStateFlow из сетевого запроса?

```
var text = MutableStateFlow("empty")
init {
text.value = zapros()
}
```

пробовал через `viewModelScope.launch {}` не сработало, если присвоить значение таким образом

```
init {
text.value = "new value"
}
```

то работает.
Насколько я понимаю присвоение не дожидается ответа из сети, что надо прописать чтоб дожидалось?

Update:
Пардон не объяснил ситуацию

```
var text = MutableStateFlow("empty")
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = zapros()
        text.emit(response)
        Log.d("TAG", "${text.value}")
    }
}
```

действительно все работает, проблема оказывается в том что не отображается в активити, в самой viewmodel работает, получается активити не дожидается?

Comment: Что значит не работает, как вы определяете работоспособность и что такое zapros()?

Comment: Вообще должно работать примерно так: `viewModelScope.launch { val response = zapros(); text.emit(response) }`